# Unable to access class from app_code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-site-project, app-code

I have a web site(not web app) which has a `default.aspx` and `default.aspx.cs`.
And it has an `App_Code` folder with class `A` in it.
So `default.aspx.cs`. Looks like:

```
namespace test1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And class `A`:

```
namespace test1
{
    public class A
    {
        _Default mDefaultRef;
        public pageLogicIndividual(_Default defaultRef)
        {
            mDefaultRef = defaultRef;
        }
    }
}
```

I can use `A` in `_Default`. eg. if I type `test1.`, while working in class `_Default`, the IntelliSense will show both classes.
But if I type `test1.`, while working in class `A`, the IntelliSense will only show `A`.
Why can't I use `_Default` in `A`?

> Error : the type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace
>   (are you missing an assembly reference )

Edit:
I'll try to clarify.
While working in the `.cs` file where class `_Default` resides I can type `test1.`, which is the namespace, and the intellisense will show me class `_Default` and Class `A`.
But if I'm working in the `.cs` file where class `A` resides and type `test1.`, which is the namespace, then the intellisense will only show me class `A`.

Comment: "f i type "test1." the IntelliSense will show both classes. But if i type "test1." in A IntelliSense will only show A." bit confusing. What exactly the behaviors is?

Comment: This is not Classic ASP - please change your tag to [tag:asp.net].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, you cannot access page classes from `App_code` classes.
This restriction comes from `website project` compilation model. Special `App_code` folder contains *shared* classes (and possibly other resources) which are available to pages (and to each other). During compilation `App_code` is compiled first in a single assembly. This is the key point. Pages, controls and MasterPages are compiled in another assembly(ies) which may have references to the `App_code` assembly (but not vise versa). So this is one-way road.
No `namespace` declaration should circumvent this behavior.
Pages can see each other in `ASP` namespace (`ASP.default_aspx`) but pages usually don't have public properties / methods (user controls `.ascx` usually have).
Read better explanation on MSDN [Code-Behind Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178138.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

I have had this challenge in the past.

Open up the App_Code folder node in Visual studio.
Right click on the concerned class, then click properties

In the properties pane, change Build Action to Compile.

It should work fine now.

Comment: Don't have that option. Only thing I have is File Name and Full Path

Comment: Whatkind of project? Website or web project? Also, what version of visual studio

Comment: It's a website project

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with your misleading `namespace` that you've added yourself after the new file has been created because *ASP.NET Web Sites* do not have namespace. The namespaces are available in *Web Applications* projects. i.e. after a new WebSite is created, namespace doesn't added to the files.

So you don't need to place your class `A` inside the `test1` namespace because you can use `A` in `default.aspx.cs` even without namespace but **you can not access other WebForm page classes from a Webform page or `App_Code` classes**.

BTW if you want to use the necessary and reusable methods within a class of the `Default` Web Form, you can move those methods out to `A` class which is under `App_Code` and as I said already you can use it within all the `Web Form CodeFiles` without providing namespace for it.